# Go sqlite fail to build/compile on mac osx

Tags: sqlite, go, darwin

i always fail to compile simple Go code every call or use sqlite library.
i use go version 1.9.7 and osx mojave (10.14.3)

sample code :

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/jmoiron/sqlx"
    _ "github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Print("connecting.")
    db := sqlx.MustConnect("sqlite3", ":memory:")
    db.Ping()
    fmt.Print("connected")
}
```

always getting this error

```
# command-line-arguments
/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64/link: /usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64/link: combining dwarf failed: Unknown load command 0x32 (50)
```

any idea ?

Comment: What does your build command look like?

Comment: go build main.go. @colminator

Answer (score 0):

We struggled with that problem for a while . We came to this solution to make the whole library as [go plugin](https://golang.org/pkg/plugin/) and compile it on a linux system and use it in other operating systems.

Comment: can you give some example for sqlite ?